# Fastest way to count pages in the database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm creating a small website with PHP and MySql, and i need a fast way to count all the pages stored in the database.
I know 3 ways to do this, but since I'm not much of an expert in PHP, MySql i have no idea which is faster or better.

The first way will be to use the PHP's `mysql_num_rows` function.

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM `pages`");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo $count;
```

The second way will be to use the MySql command `SELECT COUNT(*)`

```
$query = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `pages`"));
echo $query["COUNT(*)"];
```

And the third way will be to create a database table row to hold the total number of pages, which will increase/decrease every time i create or delete a page.

I'm not sure which one to use, I've tested all, and they work just about the same with about 200 pages.

Comment: they are not the same, fastest is 3rd, but 2nd will work too, 1st - never do this

Comment: `count(*)` always. the first one forces mysql to do all the prep work to retrieve/send all the rows in the table, and then you simply throw away all that work. on some table types, count(*) is just a metadata lookup and returns almost instantly too. for small tables, no big deal either way, but run your test again when you end up with a few billion rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Select count(*)

That sounds like the better way for a MyIsam storage engine at least, which stores that value and update it when there is any INSERT/DELETE/TRUNCATE. So there is no calculation.